# Heroku app build using generator-angular-fullstack failing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, express, angular-fullstack

I build my app using `sudo grunt build`. There are no errors. The dist folder is built and the app works great using `sudo grunt serve:dist`. When I try to deploy to heroku for the first time, it fails using `yo angular-fullstack:heroku` from project root.

I receive the following error:

```
Initializing deployment repo
Creating heroku app and setting node environment
Creating myapp... done, stack is cedar-14

https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git

{ [Error: Command failed:  !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }`
```

I have also tried following the manual build instructions on http://davemax.com/heroku-deploy-yeoman-angular-app/ and  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs. When I deploy the app using these methods, the url shows a heroku error page.

My server is an HTTPS server, so I am not sure if that is interfering with anything.

from app.js:

```
var options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.pfx'),
  passphrase: 'password'
};
// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
```

I am using the latest version of generator-angular-fullstack: version 2.0.13. I am also using the latest version of the heroku toolbelt: version 3.28.2. I'm on a linux machine, ubuntu.

Comment: if you haven't already tried this, `cd` into the `dist` folder and try again

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this. I tried again and I receive this message:

`Just found a .yo-rc.json in a parent directory.
Setting the project root at: /home/adam/Documents/dev/myapp`. It just tries to build from project root again

Answer (score 2):

I am using generator-angular-fullstack for my website and it works perfectly.

I use git bash and I have my heroku account (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication)

Always I use:

```
$grunt build

$grunt buildcontrol:heroku
```

I want to be your help.